# What level of peer review is required for Monero website updates?

Tags: getmonero-website

On 17 August 2016 0.13.0 Cobra was able to [bypass peer review](http://motherboard.vice.com/en_ca/read/a-mysterious-message-is-warning-bitcoiners-about-a-state-sponsored-attack) and issue a [Binary Safety Warning](https://bitcoin.org/en/alert/2016-08-17-binary-safety) on Bitcoin.org.

> The contributor who uploaded the alert, “Cobra-Bitcoin,” is understood to be in control of Bitcoin.org, Core developer Peter Todd told me in an encrypted message, and so they were able to bypass the peer review process for posts to the site.

How many people currently have a similar level of permission to update [getmonero.org](https://getmonero.org/) without any peer review? For [pull requests](https://github.com/monero-project/monero-site/pulls) to update the website from those without any special permissions, how much peer review is conducted before they are merged?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that fluffyponyza controls getmonero.org and ultimately has the power to update the website on his own or by merging pull requests of others. This does not seem like the type of thing that could be easily and safely delegated.

There is a formal procedure for developer contributions to Monero addressed in [this question](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/286/impact-of-collective-code-construction-contract-on-monero-development). However the procedure is likely much less formal for the website. My guess is that most relatively "harmless" pull requests such as [merchant](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1049/how-can-i-add-my-business-to-the-merchant-list-on-the-monero-website) or [moneropedia](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/1178/how-can-i-edit-a-moneropedia-definition-or-add-a-new-one) updates receive an eyeball review and critical updates such as links to new binaries or security alerts similar to the "Cobra" update to Bitcoin.org are carefully reviewed by fluffyponyza.

Comment: Pretty much this. It's not the sort of thing that could be delegated, but the Core Team and individual contributors ALWAYS double-check the SHA256 sums once new downloads are live, in case I become malicious.

Comment: @fluffyponyza "in case I become malicious." I wish more developers thought like that.