# What is the purpose of the Monero GitHub Meta repository?

Tags: development, source, monero-community, github, community

According the Hello Monero [dev meeting highlights](https://hellomonero.com/article/monero-dev-meeting-note-highlights-2016-11-13) for 2016-11-13, a new Github was created for [organizational issues](https://github.com/monero-project/meta).

What type of issues is this GitHub meant to address?

Will the same Collective Code Construction Contract, [C4 guidelines](https://monero.stackexchange.com/questions/286/impact-of-collective-code-construction-contract-on-monero-development) used for other repositories, be followed for [this one](https://github.com/monero-project/meta)?

Are non-developer community members welcome to contribute?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What type of issues is this GitHub meant to address?

From the dev meeting:

> **fluffypony:**: pigeons: do you want to tell people about the new repo we're using for issues?
>
> **pigeons:** github.com/monero-project/meta
>
> **nanoakron:** Please explain?
>
> **pigeons:** for stuff realted to build machines, build infrastructure, etc
>
> **pigeons:** anonimal has been using it some to get things setup for kovri needs
>
> **pigeons:** so feel free
>
> **fluffypony:** ok so
>
> **fluffypony:** please use /meta for organisational issues
>
> **nanoakron:** Roger
>
> **pigeons:** there is also an empty repo there now, i'll check in some build infrastructure settings there and vm templates
>
> **fluffypony:** "organisational" as in something that isn't project specific

---

> Will the same Collective Code Construction Contract, C4 guidelines used for other repos be followed for this one?

Given that the meta repository falls under the Monero Project umbrella, I assume it also applies.

---

> Are non developers community members welcome to contribute?

Of course! Note that non developers are welcome to open issues on other [Monero Project repositories](https://github.com/monero-project/) too.

Answer (score 0):

As an example, this information typically goes in a meeting announcement, submitted to the meta repository as an "issue:"

> According to sgp, we will have a Monero Community meeting on Saturday.
>   Probably we will have these topics on the agenda:
>
> Standard official meeting topics Event topics (35C3, Defcon, Camp,
>   FOSDEM, Konferenco) Hardware topics (help to advise on concluding FFS
>   90126) Surveys (plastics enclosure appearance) Kovri and Sekreta

The agenda has not been set, so it's unclear if more or less than these topics will be added. Learn more once the bug report where meeting information is stored gets published to https://github.com/monero-project/meta/issues/.